# How do I make a float in Python?

Tags: python

If I do:

```
width =  14
height = 6
aspect = width/height
```

I get the result `aspect = 2` rather than 2.33. I'm new to Python and expected it automatically cast this; have I missed something? Do I need to explicitly declare a float?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many options:

```
aspect = float(width)/height
```

or

```
width = 14.       # <-- The decimal point makes width a float.
height 6
aspect = width/height
```

or

```
from __future__ import division   # Place this as the top of the file
width =  14
height = 6
aspect = width/height
```

In Python2, division of integers returns an integer (or ZeroDivisionError). In Python3, division of integers can return a float. The

```
from __future__ import division
```

tells Python2 to make division behave as it would in Python3.